# How to display an image with URL parameters with PHP

Tags: php, html, image

I'm in the process of changing hosts and have ran into an issue displaying images. On the current host, images are served up with:

```
<img id="i1877" src="http://somewebsite.com/images/photo-shoots/XLIscjDrEAdkhzAeDsBrXIedV.jpeg?w=200&h=200">
```

However, on the new host, it won't accept the src attribute with the URL dimension parameters. All images are stored on the server in the path format:

```
/path/to/image/XLIscjDrEAdkhzAeDsBrXIedV.jpeg200x200
/path/to/image/XLIscjDrEAdkhzAeDsBrXIedV.jpeg500x500
/path/to/image/XLIscjDrEAdkhzAeDsBrXIedV.jpeg1000x1000
```

Is there an Apache2 mod or something that translates from the URL encoded src to the dimensions appended on the end of the filename? I've never seen a system set up like this and just inherited this project, so any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't add them to the file extension. Just saying. That could break things. How about going for `/path/to/image/blahblah.200.200.jpeg`?

Comment: `However, on the new host, it won't accept the src attribute with the URL dimension parameter` Why not? Who won't accept the attribute?

Comment: There is nothing "on the host" that would inhibit an image from showing up with parameters as in your original code, unless a `mod_rewrite` rule has been set up to do so. Since you would need to set up such a rule to facilitate your solution, you might as well figure out what the source of the original problem is instead.

Comment: @Matchu: I would have done something along those lines, but I wasn't involved in the site design.

Comment: @Pekka: When I change DNS settings to the new host, the image src seems to be invalid. Nothing changed between hosts during the transfer so I'm inclined to think there is a setting on the original server which translates from the URL parameters to the filename with the dimensions appended.

Comment: @btl what does "seems to be invalid" mean exactly? What happens when you open one directly? What do the error logs say? This really is the root of the problem, that's what needs fixing

Comment: @Paul: No mod_rewrite rule was specified on the original server, so I'm at a loss as to how the same image src attribute could yield different results between hosts.

Comment: @Pekka: It doesn't resolve to the proper path on the server. Basically the HTML code looks like <img id="i1877" alt="" src="http://somesite.com/images/photo-shoots/XLIscjDrEAdkhzAeDsBrXIedV.jpeg?w=200&h=200">. The new server doesn't recognize that as being a valid src path.

Comment: @btl but what does that mean exactly? What error code do you get? Do you get a 404? If you do, there will be an entry in the error log telling you what exactly went wrong.

Comment: @Pekka Sorry, it gives a 404 error. I'm not seeing anything useful in the logs; I've checked /var/log/httpd/error_log.

Comment: @btl what is the requested URL that gets 404'd? That info should be in the log file.

Comment: @Pekka: In the access_log, I see multiple occerences similar to 70.90.xxx.xxx - - [05/Oct/2010:14:07:33 -0700] "GET /images/photo-shoots/roydjukzfOKsXHXyTWCanJqBh.jpeg?w=200&h=200 HTTP/1.1" 404 3647 "http://somesite.com/tour" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100915 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.10"

Comment: And if you call that URL ` /images/photo-shoots/roydjukzfOKsXHXyTWCanJqBh.jpeg` without the part behind `?` it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest means of doing this would be to set up a `.htaccess` file that intercepts all requests to the images in that folder, parses out the image name from the URL (`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` is your friend), and then use `readfile()` to actually output the correct JPEG based on `$_REQUEST["w"]` and `$_REQUEST["h"]`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check jQuery image resize solution which is front-end solution, but it will slow down site appearance. Another solution is php image resize function, which is available for free on the net.
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/aeImageResize